# PonyORM pytest error: RuntimeError: Request object lost db_session

Tags: python, flask, pytest, ponyorm

I am trying to write some [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/contents.html) tests for my Flask app. I'm using [PonyORM](https://ponyorm.com/). All my test pass but some teardown code is running that gives the following error. How do I manage this error? What is causing it?

```
    def _exit_session(exception):
        session = getattr(request, 'pony_session', None)
        if session is None:
>           raise RuntimeError('Request object lost db_session')
E           RuntimeError: Request object lost db_session
```

[image]

Both my actual tests pass, but this teardown fails. I'm not sure where the teardown is made or how to handle it.

Comment: Can you post code of tests that are failed?